# Посоветуйте легковесный плагин, аналог popover (Bootstrap) для AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap

Чтобы можно было настраивать положение появления (top, bottom, etc...), применять свой html шаблон и чтобы скрывался при outside click или mouseout.

Comment: Пока что нашёл такой http://swangular.shopware.de.cloud2-vm153.de-nserver.de/#/popover

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rubenv/angular-rt-popup

Как написали сами разработчики

> A better version of the Bootstrap popover, for Angular.JS